# Javascript Ajax Post wrapper

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angularjs project where I built an `ajaxService` which basically wraps around an `$http.post()`. What I want to achieve is a simple service that creates an alert in case of an error, however an overwrite of the `.error()` function should not remove this alert (I want it to be called no matter what). At first I just returned the promise of the `$http.post()` but that removes the `.error()` implementation of the service when `.error()` is overwritten.

First I had this implementation:

```
  this.Post = function (url, data) {
     return $http.post(
        'Server/Server.php',
        { 'url': url, 'data': data }
     )
     .error(function (response) {
        alertsService.RenderErrorMessage(response);
     });
  }
```

But If you then implement the following, the `RenderErrorMessage()` will not be called (it's overwritten):

```
  ajaxService.Post(ajaxUrlService.GetUserGroupsByUser(), { 'userId': userService.id })
        .error(function (response) {
           userService.groups = response;
        });
```

To solve this I tried the following:

```
  this.Post = function (url, data) {
     var obj = new Object();
     obj.success = function (response) {};
     obj.error = function (response) {};

     $http.post(
     'Server/Server.php',
     { 'url': url, 'data': data }
     )
     .success(function (response) {
        if (typeof response == "String" && response.indexOf('xdebug-error') > 0) {
           alertsService.RenderErrorMessage(response);
           obj.error(response);
        }
        else {
           obj.success(response);
        }
     })
     .error(function (response) {
        alertsService.RenderErrorMessage(response);
        obj.error(response);
     });

     return obj;
  }
```

The `.Post()` doesn't return the `obj`, it returns '`undefined`'. This is not what I expected, what is the cause of the '`undefined`' and how can I solve this?

Comment: signature for `$http.post` is incorrect ...  `post(url, data, [config]);
` see docs

Comment: Your code will return undefined for obj, because `$http.post` is async.  Return a promise instead.  For handling errors in http requests, you might want to consider http interceptors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to perform some special handling of errors inside the service, but allow the error to also be handled outside the service.

https://jsbin.com/bepozi/edit?html,js,console,output

The example "wraps" the `$http` promise with another promise.  The "internal promise" performs some special handling (writes to console).  The `AppController` is then also able to perform it's own error handling by writing the error to the model.

However, for generic error handling in http requests, personally, I would use a [http interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Comment: Great example. What I was looking for was an http interceptor as you also mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using $http interceptors, a mechanism which allows you to handle requests and responses executed by the $http service, by registering your own handlers.

Declaring an interceptor:

```
module.factory('myInterceptor', ['$log', function($log) {  
$log.debug('$log is here to show you that this is a regular factory with injection');

var myInterceptor = {
    ....
    ....
    ....
};

return myInterceptor;
```

}]);

Registering it:

```
module.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {  
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('myInterceptor');
```

}]);

Read more here: http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/